# $u_{t}+cu_x=f(x+ct)$ $\implies$ $\frac{du}{dt}=f(x+ct)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'm working on a PDE problem and I came across a step I just can't figure out, would appreciate any help.

The question involves solving the general wave equation. I've got to here
$$u_{t}+cu_x=f(x+ct)$$
The problem I'm having is what comes after.

(1) How do we derive $\frac{dx}{dt}=c$?

My best guess is that for any $au_x+bu_y=g$, we can deduce that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{b}{a}$. How though?

(2) The solution defines paths $\frac{dx}{dt}=c$ and $x(h,0)=h$. What is the point of the latter?

(3) After defining the path, the biggest problem I have is how they jump to
$$\frac{du}{dt}=f(x+ct)$$

Would appreciate any help understanding any of these. Thank you

Comment: This is actually the method of characteristics in first order PDEs.

Comment: @CheeHan So are these concepts or information we should take as facts?

Comment: I wouldn't say facts, but yes these should be the very first thing you learned in first-order PDEs. You could find this in any standard PDEs textbooks. I would recommend Salsa's PDEs (: